# SQLALchemy query all() but get specific fields in list

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have this select statement where I get all ids for a particular name:
select name from table1 where id=100;

```
var1=DBSession.query(table1).filter(table1.id==100).first().name
```

This returns me with just the first name value for the id 100. However, My query results multiple names and I have to use the all clause like this

```
varlist=DBSession.query(table1).filter(table1.id==100).all()
```

Then I am trying to access name from varlist like

```
for i in varlist:
    otherlist.append(varlist.name)
```

because this query doesnt put all names in the list:

```
varlist=DBSession.query(table1).filter(table1.id==100).all().name
```

Can someone tell me how to get names from .all() directly into "varlist" without using an intermediate list?

Answer (score 2):

The `all()` method is simply syntactic sugar for calling `list` on the query. So since you want a single column and not the entity, something like this should work,

```
names = [name for name, in DBSession.query(table1.name).filter(table1.id == 100)]
```

Comment: That will give you a list of 1-tuples. You still need something like `names = map(itemgetter(0), results)` to get a flat list.

Comment: WHy do we need the comma there?

Comment: @Tania The comma is to unpack the tuples (actually a subclass) returned from the query. This is just the same as unpacking multiple tuple variables, there just are no others.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modifying @Jared's result to make this look better with .all():

namelist=[n.name for n in DBSession.query(table1).filter(table1.id==100).all()] also works. Thank you Jared.